# Using facebook login for my website

Tags: facebook, authentication

I am trying to incorporate the facebook login button into my website's homepage. I have connected it with an app, so i have the app id and secret, but i can't figure out how to check if the user is already registered to my site, so in my database, in order to preview his userprofile. I have used the javaScript sdk from facebook but when i press the facebook's login button, after the authorization, nothing happens and my website's homepage is shown again. Does anyone know how to get the user's email from the javascript sdk? I am using java servlets for my pages. I have used the code from the facebook documentation.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '8568345835', // App ID
      channelUrl : '//WWW.YOUR_DOMAIN.COM/channel.html', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
   }(document));
</script>

<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email">
```

Answer (score 4):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

**Client-side Flow**

The client-side flow also uses the OAuth Dialog for user
authentication and app authorization. The only difference is that you
must specify the `response_type` parameter with a value of token:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token
```

As with the server-side flow, you can also request additional permissions using the scope parameter:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&scope=email,read_stream&
response_type=token
```

It might be possible but it's not a best practice. I would suggest introduction of some server side scripting (i.e. PHP), but if you are using Facebook Javascript SDK only to obtain some user data than this method can be useful. Workflow would be like this.

1. User clicks Facebook Connect button that redirects to:

   > https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?
   >            client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&redirect_uri=YOUR_URL&response_type=token
2. Facebook checks YOUR_APP_ID and URL and performs authentication
3. Redirects bask to your URL.

> ```
> http://YOUR_URL#access_token=166942940015970%7C2.sa0&expires_in=64090
> ```

...with access token in URL.

Later you would extract token from URL and use it to execute FQL(Facebook Query Language) via AJAX request, and obtain user data.

Described here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 1):

After OAuth redirect and authorization, once you page is shown again, try dumping your session (something that would resemble print_r($_SESSION) in php). It should contain user data obtained from facebook.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I searched throught th facebook documantation but i am still confused about the javascript, which methods should i include....About the redirect, where do i have to put the rediraction link? sorry if these sounds like silly questions but i am completely new to this...